# jquery is not stopping after error, it's redirect other page url after error message

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a checkout page, when I submit for checkout an error message is shown, but when i click on error alert button for disable error message, then page is not stop on checkout page it's just redirected on payment gateway page .i am using this code for send data to my api.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#place_order").click(function () {
        var person1 = new Object();

        debugger;
        var quantity=$('#check2').find('#Quantity_number').val();
        if(quantity)
        {

         $('#check2').find('#Quantity').val(quantity.substring(2,quantity.length));
        }

        var amount=$('#check2').find('#Total_amount');
        $(amount).val($(amount).val().substring(1,$(amount).val().length))//replacing Rupee sign

        /* #check1 is form id , for first form , please let me know how two use second form id #check2 */
        var person = {};
        var person1 = {};

         $.map($('#check1').serializeArray(), function(n, i){
           person[n['name']] = n['value'];
         });

         $.map($('#check2').serializeArray(), function(n, i){
            person1[n['name']] = n['value'];
         });

        var mergedFormObj = $.extend({},person,person1);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser',
            type: 'Post',
            data: mergedFormObj,
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(data.ErrorMessage);
                if (data.Success) {
                    document.location.reload();  
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error in Operation');
            }
        });
    });
});   
    </script>
```

Comment: please can you edit this code for  returning incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code:

```
alert(data.ErrorMessage);
if (data.Success) {
    document.location.reload();  
}
```

The redirect takes place if, and only if, `data.Success` evaluates to `true`.  So it would seem that `data.Success` is evaluating to `true`.  Given that, you have two options:

1. If the server is returning incorrect data, correct the server-side code to return the data you expect it to return.
2. If the server can't be modified, find another way to determine "success" or "failure" from the server-side operation in your client-side code.  Perhaps the mere existence of a non-empty value in `data.ErrorMessage` would suffice?

Either way, the code is working as designed.  But the data isn't what you assume it to be.

Comment: Hey David any sample  script for this .please

Comment: @SanjayYadav: Sample script for what?  The code you already have *is* a sample script for, well, your code.

Comment: well can you edit this code for stop redirection after error message .please

Comment: @SanjayYadav: If you don't want it to redirect at all then simply remove the redirect code.  Basically, remove that entire `if` block.  You don't really need *me* to do this for you.  You can open your code in a text editor and modify it.